# jqueryMobile tap and bubbling/propagation

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, event-handling, tap, jquery-events

See this sample in android 2.x browser..its a sample to replicate a scenario in my application..

http://johnchacko.net/samples/tap.html

Its about listening to 'tap' and calling changePage from listener...

The second page is having some input fields, 'tap' event is bubbling/propagating to second page and focus is randomly set to input fields...

I read similar issues and want to know anybody experienced same issue and got a workaround for it....

Or I must use only  'click' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be fixed in few ways:

1. On tap/click event use this methods before you call changePage:

   ```
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
   ```

   or:

   ```
   $(document).on('tap', '#button', function(){       
       e.stopPropagation();
       e.stopImmediatePropagation();
       // Rest of the code
   });
   ```
2. Initialy disable all input boxes on a second page, on a pageshow event use settimeout function and enable them after cca 10 ms

Comment: thanks for reply @Gajotres
I am already doing 'e.stopPropagation();'
adding ' e.stopImmediatePropagation();' doesn't help...
issue is with android 2.x device browser.. hopes you saw the sample...

second solution will help... but its only a last option

Comment: also this is happening in a jQueryMobile applciation

Comment: Unfortunately jQuery Mobile works very bad on Android 2.X, I have searched a lot how to fix this problem on older devices and only thing that helped me was a second solution. Or you can even try, it just struck me, set settimeout  on changePage instead, I think that will work better then doing it on every possible input box.

Comment: is this a jqueryMobile issue or the issue with android 2.x browser?

Comment: mainly Android 2.X platform and then android 2.x browsers - plural, before Android 3 Google was not forcing 3rd party browsers to be a web-kit compatible.