# White flashes with phonegap + JQM app in ios

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a phonegap app that uses both AngularJS and jQuery Mobile.

I've noticed, that under ios, sometimes I get white flashes on page transitions - those are done using JQM's changePage.

I do have a fixed header and footer, which, by google, could be the source of the problem.

However, all results indicate that this was an issues that's already fixed in JQM, though it is still occuring in my app, which is running JQM 1.3.1.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I also tried adding user-scalable=no, disabling zooming and dropping data-position="fixed" from header and footer. None of these helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

to

< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

OR  add this css

```
div
{
backface-visibility:hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Chrome and Safari /
-moz-backface-visibility:hidden; / Firefox */
}

.ui-page {
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

if this not works then    check https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4024

Comment: It's already defined with user-scalable=no. I have seen the github topic, and the final solution seems to be already in the current version of JQM, so I assume it's not it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still stumbles with this, I found this post:

[how to speed up changepage in jquery mobile for phonegap app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668983/how-to-speed-up-changepage-in-jquery-mobile-for-phonegap-app)

Even though it's not entirely related, the first answer (without the js code, though it might work with it as well) solved my issue, and improved rendering in android devices as well.